# EF Core Many To Many Where On Inner Collection LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API with EF Core 2.1.

These are my (simplified) entities.

```
public class Application
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public ICollection<ApplicationDiscipline> ApplicationDisciplines { get; set; }
}

public class Discipline 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationDiscipline> ApplicationDisciplines { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DisciplineTranslation> DisciplineTranslations { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDiscipline 
{
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public Application Application { get; set; }
    public int DisciplineId { get; set; }
    public Discipline Discipline { get; set; }
}

public class DisciplineTranslation {
    public int DisciplineId { get; set; }
    public Discipline Discipline { get; set; }
    public string TranslatedDisciplineName { get; set; }
    public string TranslatedDisciplineDescription { get; set; }
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public Language { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{   
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

So there is a many to many between `Application` and `Discipline` and a one to many between `Discipline` and `DisciplineTranslation`.

Now I want to query my database with two parameters: `ApplicationName` and `LanguageKey`.

I can't seem to figure out how I can query the correct application with its disciplines and corresponding disciplinetranslations. The only thing I came up with is to add a `[NotMapped] ICollection<Disciplines> Disciplines` on `Application` and use this query.

```
var application = await Table
    .Include(a => a.ApplicationDisciplines)
    .Where(x => x.Name.Equals(appName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .Select(a => new Application()
    {
        Id = a.Id,
        Name = a.Name,
        Disciplines = a.ApplicationDisciplines
            .Select(ad => new Discipline()
            {
                Id = ad.Discipline.Id,
                DisciplineTranslations = ad.Discipline
                    .DisciplineTranslations
                    .Where(dt => dt.Language
                        .Key.Equals(languageKey, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        .ToList()
            })
    })
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

This would be so much easier without the need for `ApplicationDiscipline` by EF Core.

Which LINQ query will do the job without adding `ICollection<Discipline> Disciplines` to `Application`?

Comment: So what is the end goal item, to end up with an `Application` that Matches the name and has at least one `Discipline` that matches the language key?

Comment: Sometimes I think EF Core is two versions away from being useful - EF doesn't need the join table.

Comment: Your sample query has a `Disciplines` property in `Application` but there isn't one in your `Application` class. Also, you have `DisciplineTranslation.Language` without a type (or without a property name). And you reference `QueryParameter` but never define it.

Comment: @Gibbon my goal is to end up with 1 matching `Application` with all its `Disciplines` and for all those `Disciplines` I want the 1 matching `DisciplineTranslation` with the correct `LanguageKey`

Comment: @NetMage read above the query, there is my explanation about the `Disciplines` property. For `QueryParameter`, my mistake, this is something from the original project, I've changed my question now to match the simplified entities

Answer (score 1):

In terms of getting an `Application` as the final result, one option would be

**Include everything - Not too great:**
this would look something along the lines of
`var x = await Table.Include(a=> a.ApplicationDisciplines).ThenInclude(a=> a.Discipline).ThenInclude(a=> a.DisciplineTranslations).ThenInclude(a=> a.Language).Where( a=> a.Name == appName && a.Any(b=> b.Discipline.DisciplineTranslations.Any(c=> c.Language.Key == languageKey))).FirstOrDefaultAsync()`

I havent tested that, though chaining through the `.Any()` operation *should* work. I know you can chain it two levels deep, but untested with going through extra items.

I would say thats a bad approach though, as its likely to result in a pretty slow query overall.

**Using a Join:** Probably a better solution overall

`var aThing = ApplicationDisciplineTable.Include(x=> x.Application).Include(x=> x.Discipline).Where(x=> x.Application.Name == appName).ToList().Join(DisciplineTranslationTable.Include(x=> x.Language).Where(x=> x.Language.Key == appKey), AppDis => AppDis.DisciplineId, DisTrans => DisTrans.DisciplineId, (AppDis, DisTrans) => new {whatever details you want in here}).FirstOrDefault();`

So, the join doesnt look super clean, you *COULD* select out just an application at the end with the exact details you want in it, as you do have everything you need. But this is using a join directly on the middle objects that have been filtered down, so would only end up with the one single Discipline, Application and Language that all match the criteria

Comment: `.Any()` is not enough here. I want to get only **one** `DisciplineTranslation` with the matching `LanguageKey`. With `.Any()` we get all the `DisciplineTranslations`

Comment: @NicolasZawada I've added a way to do this using a Join on the middle many to many tables that would end up giving you 1 Application, 1 Discipline and 1 Language that all go together (which seems to be what you are looking for) - it may have slight performance hits depending on the size of the data as it will have to do the joins in memory at present due to the way EF core works with `Include()` and `Select()` entity editing which the join automatically does

Comment: @NicolasZawada also, in the first possible way, you could just use a `Select()` after to filter it down to only the one you want using `appFromQuery.ApplicationDisciplines = appFromQuery.ApplicationDisciplines.FirstOrDefault(FilterConditionsInHere);`

Comment: Indeed like your last comment, I was able to filter it down by using `Select()`. I will post my code snippet, thanks @Gibbon!

Answer (score 0):

By using `Select()` I was able to filter down to `DisciplineTranslations`.

```
var application = await Table.Include(a => a.ApplicationDisciplines)
.ThenInclude(x => x.Discipline)
.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(appName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
.Select(x => new Application(){
   Id = x.Id,
   Name = x.Name,
   ApplicationDisciplines = x.ApplicationDisciplines.Select(y => 
   new ApplicationDiscipline() {
       ApplicationId = y.ApplicationId,
       Application = y.Application,
       DisciplineId = y.Discipline.Id,
       Discipline = new Discipline() {
            Id = y.Discipline.Id
            DisciplineTranslations = y.Discipline.DisciplineTranslations.Where(z => z.Language.Key == languageKey).ToList()
       }        
   })
}).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

By using SQL Server Profiler we noticed one downfall.
In our case an application has (fortunately only) 4 `Disciplines`, so EF Core executes 1 query to get the `Application` and 4 queries to get the `DisciplineTranslations`. So there's still room for improvement.

Comment: The EF Core team says for large queries, avoiding the Cartesian explosion by using one query per level is much more efficient, so that is how they handle it. Unfortunately for you, since you are going two levels deep, you are getting multiple queries at the bottom level. It is probable that small queries would be more efficient as one query with the Cartesian product, but they don't have that flexibility.